# Unable to ingest data using python suds

Tags: python, suds, attivio

I am trying to Ingest data in Attivio (Active Intelligence Engine) using suds in python. The document id, Field name are ingested successfully. But fieldValue value is not getting populated. Here's the python code:

```
from suds.client import Client
url = "http://localhost:17000/ws/bean.attivioIngestWebService/com.attivio.webservice.service.IngestApi?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
cfg = client.factory.create('sessionConfig')
cfg.commitInterval = 1
sessionId = client.service.connect(cfg)
doc = client.factory.create('attivioDocument')
doc._id = "Doc1"

text = client.factory.create('Field')
text._name = "text"
textval = client.factory.create('fieldValue')
textval.value = "Test document text"
text.values = [textval]

doc.fields = [text]
print doc
try:
    client.service.feed(sessionId, [doc])
    client.service.commit(sessionId)
except Exception as e:
  print e
```

UPDATE:
See the difference between the .net and python SOAP below. Because `<value>` is defined as anyType, suds doesn't put the type information on it and AIE can't handle it correctly. This maybe the root of problem. Any idea how to fix it?

.net

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<feed xmlns="http://webservice.attivio.com/">
<sessionId xmlns="">704@10.7.3.7_r437gs-f879-4c58-9da5-45erf7as88ex</sessionId>
<docs readOnly="false" id="dotnet" xmlns="">
<fields name="title">
<values>
**<value xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello dot net</value>**
</values>
</fields>
</docs>
</feed>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>POST /ws/bean.attivioIngestWebService/com.attivio.webservice.service.IngestApi HTTP/1.1
```

python

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.attivio.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:feed>
         <sessionId>401@192.168.1.100_fnwsf5b5218-9159-4a8f-987a</sessionId>
         <docs id="Doc1">
            <fields name="text">
               <values>
                  **<value>Test document text</value>**
               </values>
               <metadata/>
            </fields>
            <mode/>
         </docs>
      </ns1:feed>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```